# Working with SDL on Hisilicon - Hi3516

Tags: c, arm, embedded, sdl, embedded-linux

I'm trying to use SDL library on my Hi3516 chip.

I'm able to compile my code (after setting the SDL config to `arm-hisiv300-linux-gcc`).

My code is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    SDL_Event event;

    int keypress = 0;
    int h=0; 
    setenv("SDL_FBDEV", "/dev/fb0", 1);
    setenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER", "fbcon", 1);
    setenv("SDL_MOUSEDEV", "/dev/input/event0", 1);
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ){
        printf("BBB %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    if (!(screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, DEPTH, 
        SDL_FULLSCREEN|SDL_HWSURFACE)))
    {
        printf("SDL_SetVideoMode fail\n");
        printf("BBB %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("SDL_SetVideoMode pass\n");
    SDL_Flip(screen); 
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
}
```

I see a small mouse cursor that moves when I move my mouse but in an not regular way.
Plus, my screen resolution is 1920x1080 but it only allows me to set it to 640x480.

I can elaborate about my code and my embedded system if anyone can help.

Does someone have a sample code that uses SDL on Hi3516 chip?

Comment: Please approach a [mcve], as far as that is possible for a cross-compile siutation.

Comment: I added my code. In my embedded system, I added to /lib the file libSDL-1.2.so.0

Comment: I don't think your `system()` calls do anything as they execute in child shell. Use `setenv()`. Can you use debugger to see what it waits for?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Anyone knows why I have a limit on my screen resolution?